# outlook 2016 (office 365) using incorrect time zone for emails

Tags: outlook, microsoft-office-365, timezone, microsoft-office-2016, outlook-2016

I have two users in Taipei time zone.

Both are using PCs with system time correctly set to Taipei time.

Both have an Office 365 E3 Enterprise account on the same tenant and have Office 2016 installed.

Both use Outlook 2016 for their email needs and connect to the same on-premises Exchange server.

For one user, all time stamps on email display correctly with Taipei time.

For the other user, all time stamps on email seem to be using PST time.

Why?

Everything I google seems to reference time zones in Outlook's calendar functions, but they don't even use their calendars.  This is only in reference to the email time stamps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TimeZone is set in Exchange configuration.  It is queried using `Get-MailboxRegionalConfiguration`, and configured using `Set-MailboxRegionalConfiguration`.

A user guide to modifying localization settings in Office 365 is here:  [Change your display language and time zone in Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-your-display-language-and-time-zone-in-Office-365-for-Business-6f238bff-5252-441e-b32b-655d5d85d15b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

This is typically setup during FirstRun if a user first logs into OWA.

Comment: I'm just going back through questions that I never answered.  This was two and a half years ago now, so my memory is a little fuzzy, but I believe this was the answer or close to it.  I did have to go into the Exchange server and manually set the correct time zone for the mailbox using Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this myself, and the odd problem I experienced was that the option to change time-zone simply did not show up in my browser when following the official Microsoft guide.

This turned out to be an issue with the website and Chrome, the moment I followed the same guide with Firefox the appropriate options showed up.

tl;dr have the users try the following [guide](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-your-display-language-and-time-zone-in-Office-365-for-Business-6f238bff-5252-441e-b32b-655d5d85d15b) using Firefox or Internet Explorer